# What does "publicPath" in Webpack do?

Tags: javascript, webpack

[Webpack docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) state that `output.publicPath` is:

> The `output.path` from the view of the JavaScript.

Could you please elaborate on what this actually means?

I use `output.path` and `output.filename` to specify where Webpack should output the result, but I’m not sure what to put in `output.publicPath` and whether it is required.

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("./examples/dist"),
    filename: "app.js",
    publicPath: "What should I put here?"   
  } 
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add to this question: when would you use `path` and when would you use `publicPath`?

Comment: Answer is here: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath

Comment: If helps: http://tomasalabes.me/blog/_site/web-development/2016/12/10/Webpack-and-the-public-path.html

Answer (score 187):

### `output.path`

Local disk directory to store all your output files **(Absolute path)**.

**Example:** `path.join(__dirname, "build/")`

Webpack will output everything into `localdisk/path-to-your-project/build/`

---

### `output.publicPath`

Where your browser can access uploaded bundled files. **(absolute path, or relative to main HTML file)**

**Example:** `/assets/`

Assumed you deployed the app at server root `http://server/`.

By using `/assets/`, the app will find webpack assets at: `http://server/assets/`. Under the hood, every urls that webpack encounters will be re-written to begin with "`/assets/`".

> `src="picture.jpg"` Re-writes ➡ `src="/assets/picture.jpg"`
>
> Accessed by: (`http://server/assets/picture.jpg`)
>
> ---
>
> `src="/img/picture.jpg"` Re-writes ➡ `src="/assets/img/picture.jpg"`
>
> Accessed by: (`http://server/assets/img/picture.jpg`)

Comment: `output.publicPath` has an `'auto'` option.—But what is it doing except burning extra CPU cycles for the same effect as plain `''` or `'./'` have. No clue. Who knows _that_?

Answer (score 76):

When executed in the browser, webpack needs to know where you'll host the generated bundle. Thus it is able to request additional chunks (when using [code splitting](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html)) or referenced files loaded via the [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) or [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) respectively.

For example: If you configure your http server to host the generated bundle under `/assets/` you should write: `publicPath: "/assets/"`

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the assets folder located? I would like to see the files inside assets folder
Thanks.

Answer (score 59):

<del>the publicPath is just used for dev purpose</del>, I was confused at first time I saw this config property, but it makes sense now that I've used webpack for a while

suppose you put all your js source file under `src` folder, and you config your webpack to build the source file to `dist` folder with `output.path`.

But you want to serve your static assets under a more meaningful location like `webroot/public/assets`, this time you can use `out.publicPath='/webroot/public/assets'`, so that in your html, you can reference your js with `<script src="/webroot/public/assets/bundle.js"></script>`.

when you request `webroot/public/assets/bundle.js` the `webpack-dev-server` will find the js under the dist folder

**Update:**

thanks for Charlie Martin to correct my answer

original: the publicPath is just used for dev purpose, *this is not just for dev purpose*

> No, this option is useful in the dev server, but its intention is for asynchronously loading script bundles in production. Say you have a very large single page application (for example Facebook). Facebook wouldn't want to serve all of its javascript every time you load the homepage, so it serves only whats needed on the homepage. Then, when you go to your profile, it loads some more javascript for that page with ajax. This option tells it where on your server to load that bundle from

Comment: It's not just for dev purpose, @jhnns's answer explains how it affects loader outputs.

Comment: it's the same isn't it? this property tells your loader, and your middleware where to find the real assets, hopfully you will not use webpackmiddleware , or webpack-dev-server in your production enviroment, so I think this is just for dev enviroment, please refer to http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html

Comment: From this http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath it seems this option tells webpack to fill in the correct url or path of assets in the generated files, not just for middlewares. When running dev server, I think the middleware looks at `publichPath` to hijack  requests and return the in-memory files.

Comment: exactly, in your production enviroment, your will use `webpack -p` to build your assets, and your assets should be served by your application server or your nginx server instead of webpack server or webpack middleware, so  this config no longer useful at production enviroment, am I right?

Comment: No, this option is useful in the dev server, but its intention is for asynchronously loading script bundles in production. Say you have a very large single page application (for example Facebook). Facebook wouldn't want to serve all of its javascript every time you load the homepage, so it serves only whats needed on the homepage. Then, when you go to your profile, it loads some more javascript for that page with ajax. This option tells it where on your server to load that bundle from

Comment: Checkout Section 9 on Asynchronous loading for an example...
https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto

Comment: @CharlieMartin you are right, thanks for correct me, I have update the answer

Answer (score 36):

**filename** specifies the **name of file** into which *all your bundled code is going to get accumulated after going through build step.*

**path** specifies the **output directory** where the **app.js**(filename) is going to get saved in the disk. If there is no output directory, webpack is going to create that directory for you.
for example:

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("./examples/dist"),
    filename: "app.js"
  } 
}
```

This will create a directory **myproject/examples/dist** and under that directory it creates **app.js**, **/myproject/examples/dist/app.js**. After building, you can browse to **myproject/examples/dist/app.js** to see the bundled code

**publicPath: "What should I put here?"**

**publicPath** specifies the virtual directory in **web server** from where bundled file, app.js is going to get served up from. Keep in mind, the word server when using publicPath can be either webpack-dev-server or express server or other server that you can use with webpack.

for example

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("./examples/dist"),
    filename: "app.js",
    publicPath: path.resolve("/public/assets/js")   
  } 
}
```

this configuration tells webpack to bundle all your js files into **examples/dist/app.js** and write into that file.

**publicPath** tells webpack-dev-server or express server to serve this bundled file ie **examples/dist/app.js** from specified virtual location in **server** ie /public/assets/js. So in your html file, you have to reference this file as

```
<script src="public/assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

So in summary, publicPath is like mapping between `virtual directory` in your server and `output directory` specified by output.path configuration, Whenever request for file **public/assets/js/app.js** comes, **/examples/dist/app.js** file will be served

Answer (score 23):

You can use publicPath to point to the location where you want webpack-dev-server to serve its "virtual" files. The publicPath option will be the same location of the content-build option for webpack-dev-server.  [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) creates virtual files that it will use when you start it. These virtual files resemble the actual bundled files webpack creates. Basically you will want the --content-base option to point to the  directory your index.html is in. Here is an example setup:

```
//application directory structure
/app/
/build/
/build/index.html
/webpack.config.js


//webpack.config.js
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
...
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: "/assets/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  }
};  


//index.html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
...
<script src="assets/bundle.js"></script>
</html>

//starting a webpack-dev-server from the command line
$ webpack-dev-server --content-base build
```

webpack-dev-server has created a virtual assets folder along with a virtual bundle.js file that it refers to. You can test this by going to localhost:8080/assets/bundle.js then check in your application for these files. They are only generated when you run the webpack-dev-server.

Comment: Such a good explanation, but then if i move to production or make the build by hand `/build/bundle.js` I will have to change the `src` in my `index.html` file right?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  You do not have to change the src.  Whether your in production or development, webpack will create a bundle.js in the output path.  In the above example it will be /build/bundle.js.

Comment: Thank you, I'm asking about the `src` line in index.html file. Right now it's pointing to `"assets/bundle.js"` if it move to production the bundle is going to be in `"build/bundle.js"` so i'll have to change that in the html src line to `src="build/bundle.js"`. Or is there a more automated way?

Comment: I understand your question now.  Yes you will need to change the src to build/bundle.js for production.  As for an automated way to do this, I am not sure of.  I have seen others create 2 different webpack.config.js files, one for production and one for development.  There is probably a way prgrammatically like if(ENV === production) do this... but I haven't tried that.

Comment: @ArchNoob Just a heads up on how I doing this in production now.  I did not change the src value but instead i changed my publicPath value from `/assets/` to `/build`.  This way I don't have to change my index.html.  I also moved my index.html out of the build folder and into the root of the application.

Comment: Nice trick, I recently found out about `html-webpack-plugin`. Maybe you should check it out too.. It's pretty neat!

Answer (score 18):

in my case,
i have a cdn,and i am going to place all my processed static files (js,imgs,fonts...) into my cdn,suppose the url is http://my.cdn.com/

so if there is a js file which is the orginal refer url in html is './js/my.js'
it should became http://my.cdn.com/js/my.js in production environment

in that case,what i need to do is just set publicpath equals http://my.cdn.com/
and webpack will automatic add that prefix

Comment: It doesn't seem to add any prefix in my case.

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of good answers here, so I'll focus on `output.publicPath: 'auto'`.

Say when you build your project you get the next folder structure:

```
dist/blog/index.html
dist/app.js
dist/app.css
dist/index.html
```

In this case, both our index.html files have to have a correct path to our app.js and app.css (next - assets). Let's consider the next scenarios:

- `publicPath: ''` or `publicPath: '/'`:

  When hosted on a server both point to the root of the website (ex. https://localhost:8080/), so everything works fine.

  But should you try to open them locally, `blog/index.html` won't have a correct path to the assets. In case of `publicPath: ''` assets will be searched in the `blog/` folder since that's where the relative path is pointing to. `index.html` still has the correct path to assets.

  And in case of `publicPath: '/'`, `/` points to the root of the filesystem, so neither of our index.html files will have a correct path to assets.
- `publicPath: 'auto'`:

  In this case, both our index.html files will have relative paths to the assets. So, `blog/index.html` will be pointing to `../app.css`, and `index.html` will be pointing to `app.css`.

Answer (score 4):

The webpack2 documentation explains this in a much cleaner way:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#use-cases

> webpack has a highly useful configuration that let you specify the base path for all the assets on your application. It's called publicPath.

Answer (score 2):

publicPath is used by webpack for the replacing relative path defined in your css for refering image and font file.