# webpack-dev-server not bundling to output file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am able to webpack with my webpack.config.js as is, and the changes are reflected when I view my index.html in the browser without using webpack-dev-server.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app/');
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public/');


var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    publicPath: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  watch: true,
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

When I try to run webpack-dev-server with a watch on my files, the service recognizes that a save was made, returns "Compiled Successfully" and the app indicates that it is refreshing at my localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/, but does not update the bundle.js designated in the output. I have seen a lot of questions that are resolved by including the publicPath key value pair, however I already have that included, and I am still unable to see the edits when my server hot updates.

The following are the packages installed in the directory

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  }
}
```

And my jsx file being compiled is a simple first react component

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <p>Hello World!</p>;
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your webpack config to the following:
(Note: I changed APP_DIR and BUILD_DIR just to test it here.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/');


var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  watch: true,
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.js?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: APP_DIR
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Note that I changed:

- `output.publicPath`: this is relative to server root, and not a absolute path. More info: [What does "publicPath" in webpack do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846814/what-does-publicpath-in-webpack-do)
- `devServer.contentBase`: I changed this so the html file inside `/src` dir would be hit when I run the server.

This should work! =)

Comment: I had to change the public path to match the BUILD_DIR, but the other changes worked! Thank you very much!