# Images GETs throw 404 error in production using Webpack and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, webpack, path, relative-path, webpack-3

I have this conundrum I can't solve after many tryouts:

> **I'm unable to load static images in production;**
>
> everything is fine while developing (*npm run serve*), even when serving files from dist (*npm run serve:dist*)

### Versions

Webpack: 3.12.0

file-loader: 1.1.11

url-loader: 1.1.2

AngularJS: 1.6.9

### While developing:

My index.html contains this line and webpack won't load without

```
<base href="/"></base>
```

while my AngularJS config block contains

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

I use an URL like 
*http://localhost:3000/#/appName/listingComponent/users*

and I'm able to see every image using the **ng-src** (sometimes it's dynamically binded) like this

```
<img ng-src="app/images/image1.png">
```

the folder structure is like this

```
ui/
├── conf/
│   ├── browsersync-dist.conf.js
│   ├── browsersync.conf.js
│   ├── gulp.conf.js
│   ├── webpack-dist.conf.js
│   └── webpack.conf.js
├── gulp_tasks/
│   ├── browsersync.js
│   ├── misc.js
│   └── webpack.js
├── node_modules/
├── src/
│   ├── app/
│   │   ├── config.js  //global variables
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── index.less
│   │   ├── images/ <--
│   │   ├── actual_app_folders/
│   │   └── ...
├── gulpfile.js
└── package.json
```

In my webpack-dist.js I have the following

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders: [
          'json-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/
        ],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/
        ],
        loaders: [
          'eslint-loader'
        ],
        enforce: 'pre'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|less)$/,
        exclude: '/node_modules/roboto-fontface/',
        loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader?minimize!less-loader!postcss-loader'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: [
          'html-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|eot|woff|ttf|svg|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    FailPlugin,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: conf.path.src('/app/index.html'),
      inject: true,
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['vendors', 'config'],
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('index-[contenthash].css'),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        postcss: () => [autoprefixer]
      }
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: conf.paths.dist,
    filename: function(output) {
      return output['chunk']['name'] === 'config' ? '[name].js' : '[name]-[hash].js';
    },
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },
  entry: {
    app: `./${conf.path.src('/app/index')}`,
    config: `./${conf.path.src('/app/config')}`,
    vendors: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).concat(['webpack-material-design-icons'])
  }
};
```

### IN PRODUCTION

The build process adds the `/customer_company_name/our_company_name/` prefix to the path, which becomes

```
http://<customer_domain>:<domain_port>/customer_company_name/our_company_name/#/appName/listingComponent/users
```

while the folder structure is like this

```
our_company_name/
├── app/
│   ├── images/ <--
│   │   ├── image1.png
│   │   └── image2.png
├── app-<random_number>.js
├── config.js
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── index-<random_number>.css
└── vendors.js
```

> **THE PROBLEM**
>
> Now every time there's a pic to be shown, the browser gets a 404 error
>   like this

```
GET http://<customer_domain>:<domain_port>/app/images/image1.png 404 (Not Found)
```

while the request should be made like this

```
GET http://<customer_domain>:<domain_port>/customer_company_name/our_company_name/index.js
```

like every other file in the application does.

### What I tried

So far nothing of the following helped:

1. Change base tag upon build process in the following `<base href="/customer_company_name/our_company_name/"></base>` (this is currently retained)
2. Explicitly requiring the pictures together with every other file in the index.js `require('./images/ODM_trasp48px.png');` (this is currently retained)
3. Using publicPath in webpack `output.publicPath: '/customer_company_name/our_company_name/'` and also `output.publicPath: '/'`
4. Using file-loader instead of url-loader (this is currently retained)
5. Using file-loader with `options: { useRelativePath: true }`
6. Using file-loader with `options: { publicPath: /customer_company_name/our_company_name/ }`

Can you help me lads, please?

Comment: Wild guess, but have you tried $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); to eliminate the hashbang?
Also, the base tag must end with a slash and the sources must not start with a slash.
As far as I can tell, this should have worked out of the box. Could you provide an angular template with img tags?

Comment: In the beginning, I had `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` but it made the app throw 404 errors when trying to redirect to a specific page once the app crashed (via `$location.path('/'); return $window.location.reload();`). I agree that it should have worked out of the box, even using the hashbang; the other thing I initially did was moving the `index.*` files from `src/` to `src/app`. The base tag has already a trailing slash in its src, are you referring to something else?

Comment: 1. ```$location.path('/')``` doesn't work without reloading the page?
2. Have you tried moving the static files out of the src folder, and tell webpack to copy them to the desired location?

Comment: 1. yes, but that's the use we meant for the "redirect", probably a misuse of the term indeed 2. no since that looks I'll have the same problem, but with extra steps P.S.: I think in the previous comment you meant "the base tag is a self-closing type" thank you for the observation

Comment: are you deploying it on iis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
Let's start with

`output.publicPath: '/customer_company_name/our_company_name/'`

this will take care of rewriting ng-/src paths correctly as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38748466/4277702).

We won't need the `html-loader` to parse ng-/src, the only thing needed is to always use ng-src, or the build won't be successful.

Eventually, there's no need of `<base>` tag and neither the initial slash in every path used to refer to images.

I'll update this answer as I improve the `webpack-dist.conf.js`/the whole project for the better.

---

No answer given worked per se, hence I'll try combinations of them since some suggestions look legit.

Eventually, if I won't be able to solve this, I'll try to drop the production path prefix `/customer_company_name/our_company_name/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with the replacement pattern since it works for other file types, but the fact that webpack does not know what to do with ng-src attribute. I think it only looks at the img's src attribute by default. You can change it to recognize ng-src like:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
    ...
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loaders: [ "html-loader?" + JSON.stringify({ attrs: ["img:src", "img:ng-src"] })]
    },
    ...
  ],
   ...
```

alt syntax:

```
{
   test: /\.html$/,
   loaders: [ "html-loader?attrs=img:src img:ng-src" ]
}
```

Before changing your config, you can just test whether that is the reason by checking if the replacement currently works correctly for img tags with a plain static <img src="..."/>.

Comment: This looks legit, but I'm currently trying to add it and it doesn't seem to work. Since there's a lot more in play in that webpack-dist.js can you please add it to the original file together with the other parts I should retain/add to it?

Comment: Just use it to replace the section for "html-loader" in your loaders. If it makes no difference, then the reason is something else.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work per se, but I'll try it in different combinations of file-loader options and src paths

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting webpack parsing your templates, you might try to **explicitly import your image(s)** and pass it to your template.

The imported images will be then processed by the configured `image-loader` or `url-loader`.

### Static image

```
const myImage = require('./path/to/images/image1.png');

// In component declaration 
`<img ng-src="${myImage}">`
```

### Dynamic image

Using webpack's [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context)

```
const pathToImages = require.context('./path/to/images', true);
const dynamicImageName = 'foo.jpg',

// In component declaration 
`<img ng-src="${pathToImages(dynamicImageName, true)}">`
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below change into your index.html

```
<base href="./"></base>
```