# What for is base parameter in router in vue/cli?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I created new @vue/cli 4.0.5 app and in file 
src/router/index.js I see :

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
```

I do not have any BASE_URL parameter in .env at my local and running under the localhost with command :

```
npm run serve
```

I work locally ok

I deployed the app under live server under apache(ubuntu 16) into hosting root also not using this parameter.

What is it ? Is it the same as publicPath( https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicPath )?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`process.env.BASE_URL` is [automatically injected](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code) into Webpack configuration by Vue CLI with the value specified in CLI config (`vue.config.js`) variable [publicPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicPath)

### What is it used for ?

From the docs:

> The base URL your application bundle will be deployed at. This is the equivalent of webpack's `output.publicPath`, but Vue CLI also needs this value for other purposes, so you should always use `publicPath` instead of modifying webpack `output.publicPath`
>
> By default, Vue CLI assumes your app will be deployed at the root of a domain, e.g. `https://www.my-app.com/`. If your app is deployed at a sub-path, you will need to specify that sub-path using this option. For example, if your app is deployed at `https://www.foobar.com/my-app/`, set publicPath to `'/my-app/'`

So in Webpack [it is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846814/what-does-publicpath-in-webpack-do) to link to additional resources (images, fonts, code chunks when code-splitting)

The same purpose is in Vue Router because it also creates links (to other parts of your application) via `<router-link>`

For example with this route:

```js
    {
      path: "/page1",
      name: "Page 1",
      component: Page1
    }
```

and this in your template:

```html
<router-link to="/page1">Page 1</router-link>
```

If router is set to `base: '/'` (default), the link will be rendered as

```html
<a href="/page1" class="">Page 1</a>
```

but with `base: '/my-app/'`, the link becomes

```html
<a href="/my-app/page1" class="">Page 1</a>
```

You can read more about Absolute vs relative URLs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: What is practical  use if it? Like I have hosting root in '/var/www/html' and if I need to set several apps under them in separate subdirectory for any app I have in base parameter set this subdirectory? Or what ? Please, link to practical example

Comment: @PetroGromovo I'v added more details and examples with regards to Vue Router