# Vue.js / Webpack build "index.html" using a "static" subdomain for CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have a Vue.js project that is working fine in localhost.

But when I build and deploy to production, I need the static files (.css and .js) to be served on a "static" subdomain.

For example, my main URL:

```
https://www.example.com/index.html
```

The static assets will be:

```
https://static.example.com/css/app.50f83e17.css
https://static.example.com/js/chunk-vendors.6f495bf3.js
```

When I run "npm run build" Webpack build the "index.html" file loading like this:

```
<link href=/css/app.50f83e17.css rel=stylesheet>
```

But I need the href to be like this:

```
<link href=https://static.example.com/css/app.50f83e17.css rel=stylesheet>
```

How do I configure Vue.js or Webpack to build the "index.html" using a different subdomain for the CSS and JS?

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you would need to use *webpack publicPath*

You can configure webpack to build index.html using a different subdomain,

webpack.config.js

```
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
  output: {
    ..
    publicPath: 'https://static.example.com/js/',
  },
};
```

*npm run build* Webpack build the "index.html" would have

```
..
..
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.example.com/js/chunk-vendors.6f495bf3.js"></script>
```

For css,

webpack.config.js

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: 'https://static.example.com/css/',
            },
          },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

You can also specify publicPath at runtime,

entry.js

```
__webpack_public_path__ = myRuntimePublicPath;

// rest of your application entry
```

Note: please consider adding a environment variable instead of hardcoding the asset CDN path, and pass the environment variable via npm scripts, alternately you can also define a global publicPath

`var myRuntimePublicPath = 'https://static.example.com/js/'`

and use it in the entry file (say entry.js) as displayed above.

refer: [webpack publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) and [mini-css-extract-plugin publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#publicpath)

**In case of using Vue Router**

The base URL your application bundle will be deployed at publicPath (known as baseUrl before Vue CLI 3.3).

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? 'https://static.example.com/js/'
    : '/'
}
```

Vue Router

// override the base to hardcoded default value as it gets the value from publicPath

```
base: '/'
```

This will allow subdomain for javaScript bundle of vuejs build.

Comment: If OP is using Vue Router, they need to make sure the [`base`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base) property is **not** set to `publicPath`

Comment: I am using Vue Router, and the base property is the default '/'.

Comment: updated answer for vue.config.js, please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218186/3679048

what you could do in my opinion is to preserve the default value of base by hardcoding it; base: '/'. This way it won;t receive the publicPath value for routing and your asset files would still be served from the desired subdomains.